How does God know things if He is immaterial?
In our material reality, made of composite beings, knowledge appears to correspond to storage in or interaction with a physical substance (e.g., memory stored in the brain). If God is immaterial and indivisible, how is knowledge possible in such a being? Have any philosophers offered explanations or models to reconcile this issue?

How does one presume to know any detail about god?

Thomas Aquinas Emulator can be interrogated interactively to explain how this is understood in Christian theology.

@keshlam that’s part of the point, in what sense is god a good explanation if no one knows how he works?

Until very recently, we really understood very little about how most things work. There are still plenty of things that we don't understand. That doesn't mean we can't observe, or infer, their presence. Or what we think is their presence. In what sense is dark matter a good explanation when we don't know how it works? Well, it makes the numbers balance and lettuce make reasonable predictions, and those of us who want the details just have to continue researching, or hope that somebody else is doing so, and if we're lucky we may eventually know. God is, in many ways, a similar placeholder.

@keshlam, I assume "lettuce" was a result of autocomplete...  ;)

@MichaelHall: yeah, autodefect. I have got to learn not to answer these on my phone, or to triple check before the editing time limit elapses.

He does not know [a process]; he is knowledge [an attribute].
See Spinoza's Ethics, II Prop.I:

Thought is an attribute of God, or God is a thinking thing. Particular thoughts, or this and that thought, are modes which, in a certain conditioned manner, express the nature of God. God therefore possesses the attribute of which the concept is involved in all particular thoughts, which latter are conceived thereby. Thought, therefore, is one of the infinite attributes of God, which express God's eternal and infinite essence. In other words, God is a thinking thing.

And see Spinoza: Knowledge in the Ethics:

Thought is an infinite power of thinking that is God’s idea of himself, while we, our minds and all our thoughts, are so many ways God modifies himself by constitutively expressing himself through an indefinite amount of finite thoughts. In other words, God has and is every idea, while we are just our idea of our ideas of our body and the other bodies that affect us.


The OP’s question is how God knows, not how God thinks. The quote Ethics, II, Prop. 1 is about thinking, not about knowing. Also the second quote from IEP is about thought, not about knowing. -  Does Spinoza really deal with the question how God knows? From where is your first remark: God is knowledge? - Even if it were from Spinoza I do not understand what it means. It reminds me on Wittgenstein: "For philosophical problems arise when language goes on holiday" :-)

Many people who believe in God also believe that the nature of God is simply unknowable by mere humans. So your question is simply unanswerable, because he's a supernatural being outside our understandings of physics.
